# Pattern matching fails for password

Tags: java, regex

My password condition is, minimum 8 characters, minimum one special character, minimum one numeric

For this I wrote a simple class to verify, but eventually fails.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
public class PasswordVerifier {
    private static final String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "(`~!@#$%^&*()_+=-][;'/.,\\<>?|:\"}{)";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            String password = in.readLine();
            if(!password.matches("^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[SPECIAL_CHARACTERS]).*$")){
                System.out.println("Password does not satisfy compliant");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Yes.. gets through");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is "but eventually fails." supposed to mean?

Comment: does it only fail with certain special characters? have you confirmed that when SPECIAL_CHARACTERS is merged in, that all the characters are appropriately escaped? I've never seen that approach to forming a regex string. are you sure it works, and you are not just requiring that one of the characters in the literal 'SPECIAL_CHARACTERS' is present?

Comment: Is there a contest requiring that you do it all in a single match?  Do three separate tests: Test1: Length >= 8.  Test2: Contains a special character.  Test3: Contains a numeric digit.  There's a lot of value in the maintainability that comes with a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for your requirement:

```
private static final String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "(`~!@#$%^&*()_+=-\\]\\[;'/.,\\<>?|:\"}{)";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        String password = in.readLine();
        if(!password.matches("((?=.*\\d)(?=.*["+SPECIAL_CHARACTERS+"]).{8,})")){
            System.out.println("Password does not satisfy compliant");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Yes.. gets through");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The regex specifies:

- Input must contains one digit from 0-9
- Must contains one special symbols in the list of SPECIAL_CHARACTERS that you've defined
- Length should be at least 8 characters

Comment: The pattern still won't work because `SPECIAL_CHARACTERS` contains "]", which will destroy the r.e. syntax.

Comment: This works for me.. My bad!.. didn't concatenate the special character string and it failed on special characters. Thanks all for your quick response.

Comment: @TedHopp: But I escaped the "]" with "\\\]"

Answer (score 2):

I would not bother trying to write a regular expression. A r.e. that includes all your conditions and nothing more would be difficult to write, harder to understand, and probably not terribly efficient. Just code your requirements explicitly:

```
boolean isAcceptablePassword(String pwd) {
    boolean numeric = false, special = false;
    if (pwd.length() >= 8) {
        for (int i = pwd.length() - 1; !numeric && !special && i >= 0; --i) {
            char c = pwd.charAt(i);
            numeric = numeric || Character.isDigit();
            special = special || SPECIAL_CHARACTERS.indexOf(c) >= 0;
        }
    }
    return numeric && special;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `]` or `-` in the middle if a character class, because they have a meaning for the character class syntax. If you want them in there, they have to be the first two elements in the class, `-` before `]`.